# Qt unable to connect slots of a class when connecting to protected member of inherited class

Tags: qt, slot

I am quite new with Qt and I've been playing with it. Recently while working on one of my projects, I've ran into something I don't understand. For some reason, in the class `JoinWindow`, I can't connect my protected slots to anything, while I can still make connection with other slots.

Here's my header :

```
#ifndef JOINWINDOW_H
#define JOINWINDOW_H

#include "mywindow.h"

class JoinWindow : public MyWindow
{
public:
     JoinWindow(QString name = "Guess");

protected slots:
     void on_buttonConnexion_clicked();

};

#endif // JOINWINDOW_H
```

My cpp :

```
#include "joinwindow.h"

JoinWindow::JoinWindow(QString name)
:MyWindow(name)
{
     buttonConnexion->setText("Connexion"); // protected member of MyWindow

     connect(buttonServer, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_buttonConnexion_clicked()));
}

void JoinWindow::on_buttonConnexion_clicked()
{
    // Code in slot won't get called when the button is clicked
}
```

Here's the header file of MyWindow :

```
#ifndef MYWINDOW_H
#define MYWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class MyWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWindow(QString name = "Guess");
    ~MyWindow();

    // Some fonctions here and Slots

protected:
    QPushButton *buttonServer;

    // More objects
};

#endif // MYWINDOW_H
```

What is weird and I don't understand, is that I don't get any compilation errors and my program works perfectly fine. It won't call the Slot `on_buttonConnexion_clicked()` when the button is pressed though. What is even weirder is that is I connect a SLOT that isn't part of `JoinWindow` class, it will call the SLOT just fine and work as intended on a click of the button.

```
#include "joinwindow.h"

JoinWindow::JoinWindow(QString name)
:MyWindow(name)
{
     buttonConnexion->setText("Connexion"); // protected member of MyWindow

     connect(buttonServer, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}

void JoinWindow::on_buttonConnexion_clicked()
{

}
```

This code will close the app when the button is clicked. I can also connect to SLOTS of the class `MyWindow` just fine, for some reason it can't connect to the SLOTS of `JoinWindow` only.

Comment: There must be something I don't understand as if I add the definition of the SLOT in MyWindow it all works fine, can't you call new slots in children class or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run qmake after creating a new slot. did you run it?

Also you need to add Q_OBJECT in JoinWindow since in inherits from a Q_OBJECT. like this:

```
#ifndef JOINWINDOW_H
#define JOINWINDOW_H

#include "mywindow.h"

class JoinWindow : public MyWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     JoinWindow(QString name = "Guess");

protected slots:
     void on_buttonConnexion_clicked();

};

#endif // JOINWINDOW_H
```

Add the Q_OBJECT macro and run qmake. I believe that should fix it.